# Next.js building timings

Tags: next.js

I am currently looking for a way to track time (in ms/sec) spent on Next.js building steps and write this information into json file. So in the end I would like to have something like

```
{
 "js": 10000,
 "css": 5000,
 ...
}
```

I could not find any tools available for solving this task.

There is also a /.next/trace file created during "next build" and containing some data like

```
[{"traceId":"0350c99bb05551a7","parentId":"2071643884994g71","name":"build-module-json","id":"89936a6d306d4411","timestamp":13930168804,"duration":6869574, ...}]
```

but Im not sure if its data could be useful as there is no detail information on this file in docs.

Thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 0):

found a solution speed-measure-webpack-plugin

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).